# JB4A Android initialization fails because of "bad base-64"

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, bug

I see the following non-fatal error quite often in our Crashlytics:

```
[~!ud                     ] bad base-64 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET PUSH SDK VERSION: 4.7.1 build 160600004 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  APP VERSION: 7.1.2 : 701029 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Debug version: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  configureSdk() Initialized with:  ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Context: de.mycompany.android.MyApplication@4123a058 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET App Id: {et_app_id} ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Access Token: {access_token} ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GCM Sender ID: {gcm_sender_id} ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Analytics: true ~!ETPush_ERROR:  WAMA: true ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Location: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Proximity: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  CloudPages: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION AVAILABLE: true ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION: 9877000
[~!ETPush                 ] Unable to initialize encryption ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET PUSH SDK VERSION: 4.7.1 build 160600004 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  APP VERSION: 7.1.2 : 701029 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Debug version: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  configureSdk() Initialized with:  ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Context: de.mycompany.android.MyApplication@4123a058 ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET App Id: {et_app_id} ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Access Token: {access_token} ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GCM Sender ID: {gcm_sender_id} ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Analytics: true ~!ETPush_ERROR:  WAMA: true ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Location: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Proximity: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  CloudPages: false ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION AVAILABLE: true ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION: 9877000
ET push config failed! com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETException: Unable to initialize encryption at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush$1.run(SourceFile:458) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

JB4A Android SDK Version: 4.7.1

I've seen it on Android-Versions from 4.x to 6.x.

Is there something I can do on our side, or is this an SDK bug?

Answer (score 0):

Our use of Base64.encodeToString() has been in the SDK since the Summer of 2015 and we have never observed this error.  The SDK is dependent on `import android.util.Base64;`.

If you require any further assistance please open an internal support ticket so we can work through any code specific issues with your application and/or any included libraries you are using.

Comment: Could you send me an URL where I can open an internal support ticket?

Comment: You would do that through your Salesforce Account Manager.  I am unaware of any other method.